# Best way of passing arguments to ember addon source code

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

### TL;DR

Is it possible to pass the options from the addon's `index.js` file to the addon's Ember application?

### More detail

Ember CLI addon's allow you to pass options to an addon by setting options in your `Brocfile.js`.

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

var app = new EmberApp({
  myAddon: {
    enabled: false // TODO - Change when CLoudfront is implemented
  },
});
```

You can then access these options in the addon's `index.js` file like so:

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'my-addon',

  included: function(app) {
    var options = app.options.myAddon;
  }
}
```

However, what if I want to use these options in an Ember component or view or other class in the addon? For example, a component:

```
import Em from 'ember';

export default Em.Component.extend({
  
  doSomething: function() {
    if (this.get('options.enabled')) {
      // Then do something
    }
  },

});
```

Is it possible to pass the options from the addon's `index.js` file to the addon's Ember application?

Please note, I'm aware you could just pass the argument to the component in the template but that's not the point of this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're trying to accomplish is best implemented using `config/environment`.

You can either add your options to your addons `config/environment.js` [file](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/blueprints/addon/files/addon-config/environment.js). This object will be merged with you applications `config/environment.js`.

```
module.exports = function(/* environment, appConfig */) {
  return {
    myaddon {
      enabled: true
    }
  };
};
```

Or if you are feeling funky, you can override the default behaviour of the [addons config hook](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/a-compendium-of-hooks-in-embercli#config) in `index.js` to manually add the options. But the happy path should be considered adding it to `config/environment.js`

In your component you can then import the config with:

```
import config from '../config/environment';
```

If you also need the options to be added to your app instance. You can add the options under the `APP` property in `config/environment.js`. The content of the APP property are added to the app instance. In your addon's `config/environment.js` put:

```
module.exports = function(/* environment, appConfig */) {
  return {
    APP: {
     // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
     // when it is created
      myaddon {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  };
};
```